# operation in /dev/shm causes overflow

Tags: linux, memory, shared-memory

I am repeating tens of thousands of similar operations in /dev/shm, each with a directory created, files written, and then removed. My assumption used to be that I was actually creating directories and removing them in place, so the memory consumption had to be quite low. However it turned out the usage was rather high, and finally caused memory overflow. So my questions is: with operations like

```
mkdir /dev/shm/foo
touch /dev/shm/foo/bar
[edit] /dev/shm/foo/bar
....
rm -rf /dev/shm/foo
```

Will it finally cause memory overflow? and if it does, why is that, since it seems to be removing them in-place.

**Note:** this is a tens of thousands similar operation.

Comment: Kernel bug perhaps related? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309898/unlinking-files-in-dev-shm-not-freeing-memory

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Curious, as you're running this application what does `df -h /dev/shm` show your RAM usage to be?

#### tmpfs

By default it's typically setup with 50% of whatever amount of RAM the system physically has. This is [documented here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt) on kernel.org, under the filesystem documentation for tmpfs. Also it's mentioned in the `mount` man page.

*excerpt from [mount man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount)*

> The maximum number of inodes for this instance. The default is half of
>   the number of your physical RAM  pages,  or (on a machine with
>   highmem) the number of lowmem RAM pages, whichever is the lower.

#### confirmation

On my laptop with 8GB RAM I have the following setup for `/dev/shm`:

```
$ df -h /dev/shm
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                 3.9G  4.4M  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
```

#### What's going on?

I think what's happening is that in addition to being allocated 50% of your RAM to start, you're essentially consuming the entire 50% over time and are pushing your `/dev/shm` space into swap, along with the other 50% of RAM.

Note that one other characteristic of `tmpfs` vs. `ramfs` is that `tmpfs` can be pushed into swap if needed:

*excerpt from [geekstuff.com](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/overview-of-ramfs-and-tmpfs-on-linux/)*

```
                    Table: Comparison of ramfs and tmpfs

Experimentation                          Tmpfs                Ramfs
---------------                          -----                -----
Fill maximum space and continue writing  Will display error   Will continue writing
Fixed Size                               Yes                  No
Uses Swap                                Yes                  No
Volatile Storage                         Yes                  Yes
```

At the end of the day it's a filesystem implemented in RAM, so I would expect it to act a little like both. What I mean by this is that as files/directories are deleted your're using some of the physical pages of memory for the inode table, and some for the actual space consumed by these files/directories.

Typically when you use space on a HDD, you don't actually free up the physical space, just the entries in the inode table, saying that the space consumed by a specific file is now available.

So from the RAM's perspective the space consumed by the files is just dirty pages in memory. So it will dutifully swap them out over time.

It's unclear if `tmpfs` does anything special to clean up the actual RAM used by the filesystem that it's providing. I saw mention in several forums that people saw that it was taking upwards of 15 minutes for their system to "reclaim" space for files that they had deleted in the `/dev/shm`.

Perhaps this paper I found on `tmpfs` titled: [tmpfs: A Virtual Memory File System](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~vcss544/tmpfs.pdf) will shed more light on how it is implemented at the lower level and how it functions with respect to the VMM. The paper was written specifically for SunOS but might hold some clues.

#### experimentation

The following contrived tests seem to indicate `/dev/shm` is able to clean itself up.

#### experiment #1

Create a directory with a single file inside it, and then delete the directory 1000 times.

*initial state of `/dev/shm`*

```
$ df -k /dev/shm
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                  3993744      5500   3988244   1% /dev/shm
```

*fill it with files*

```
$ for i in `seq 1 1000`;do mkdir /dev/shm/sam; echo "$i" \
      > /dev/shm/sam/file$i; rm -fr /dev/shm/sam;done
```

*final state of `/dev/shm`*

```
$ df -k /dev/shm
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                  3993744      5528   3988216   1% /dev/shm
```

#### experiment #2

Create a directory with a single 50MB file inside it, and then delete the directory 300 times.

*fill it with 50MB files of random garbage*

```
$ start_time=`date +%s`
$ for i in `seq 1 300`;do mkdir /dev/shm/sam;                     \
   dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/shm/sam/file$i bs=52428800 count=1 > \
   /dev/shm/sam/file$i.log; rm -fr /dev/shm/sam;done              \
   && echo run time is $(expr `date +%s` - $start_time) s

...
8 bytes (8 B) copied, 0.247272 s, 0.0 kB/s
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
9 bytes (9 B) copied, 1.49836 s, 0.0 kB/s
run time is 213 s
```

*final state of `/dev/shm`*

Again there was no noticable increase in the space consumed by `/dev/shm`.

```
$ df -k /dev/shm
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                  3993744      5500   3988244   1% /dev/shm
```

#### conclusion

I didn't notice any discernible effects with adding files and directories with my `/dev/shm`.  Running the above multiple times didn't seem to have any effect on it either. So I don't see any issue with using `/dev/shm` in the manner you've described.

Comment: Thanks @sim, That's an impressive test, though I think I have had a sense where goes wild. It may be due to the writing of one file, which grabbed away all available memories. I will double check it and possibly come back to you later