# Ubuntu 20.04 electron based apps (slack, teams, chrome) crashed after tmpfs reached 100%

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chrome, microsoft-teams, slack-desktop

I'm observing similar issues mentioned here

[operation in /dev/shm causes overflow](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79364/operation-in-dev-shm-causes-overflow)

I've 32GB, Ubuntu 20.04, Kernel 5.14, AMD RYZEN, 25GB of swap.

> Linux FP-LSC0727L 5.14.0-1048-oem #55-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 8 14:58:10 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

> tmpfs                      6,0G  6,0G     0 100% /dev/shm

After reaching 100% of tmpfs all electron based apps crashed. And I am not able to run it again, but when resize the /dev/shm

> sudo mount -o remount,size=10G /dev/shm

I can get it back to work for a while, until the additional mem got used. I've tried to downgrade kernel to 5.13 and upgrade to

> uname -a
> Linux FP-LSC0727L 5.15.0-46-generic #49~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 4 19:15:44 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

It didn't helped at all. The logs from slack when it crashed

> /var/log/syslog

seems like

> Aug 23 11:21:53 FP-LSC0727L slack.desktop[4357]: [4357:0823/112153.759453:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(94)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: AllocateAndMapSharedMemory failed
> Aug 23 11:21:53 FP-LSC0727L slack.desktop[4357]: [4357:0823/112153.759551:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(46)] Received unexpected number of handles
> Aug 23 11:21:53 FP-LSC0727L slack.desktop[4357]: [4357:0823/112153.759581:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(94)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: AllocateAndMapSharedMemory failed
> Aug 23 11:21:53 FP-LSC0727L slack.desktop[4357]: [4357:0823/112153.759666:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(46)] Received unexpected number of handles
> Aug 23 11:21:53 FP-LSC0727L slack.desktop[4357]: [4357:0823/112153.759694:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(94)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: AllocateAndMapSharedMemory failed
> Aug 23 11:21:53 FP-LSC0727L slack.desktop[4357]:
> ...MORE SIMILAR LINES...
> Aug 23 11:21:53 FP-LSC0727L slack.desktop[4357]: [4357:0823/112153.761103:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(94)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: AllocateAndMapSharedMemory failed
> Aug 23 11:21:53 FP-LSC0727L slack.desktop[4357]: [4357:0823/112153.761230:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(46)] Received unexpected number of handles
> Aug 23 11:21:53 FP-LSC0727L slack.desktop[4357]: [4357:0823/112153.761275:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(94)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: AllocateAndMapSharedMemory failed
> Aug 23 11:21:53 FP-LSC0727L slack.desktop[4357]: [4357:0823/112153.761389:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(46)] Received unexpected number of handles

> google-chrome -v
> [28114:28114:0823/120623.888519:ERROR:platform_shared_memory_region_posix.cc(217)] Creating shared memory in /dev/shm/.com.google.Chrome.XQhry3 failed: No space left on device (28)
> [28114:28153:0823/120623.888743:ERROR:platform_shared_memory_region_posix.cc(217)] Creating shared memory in /dev/shm/.com.google.Chrome.vldHe2 failed: No space left on device (28)
> [28114:28114:0823/120623.888758:ERROR:platform_shared_memory_region_posix.cc(217)] Creating shared memory in /dev/shm/.com.google.Chrome.1QE8A4 failed: No space left on device (28)
> Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

slack                   4.27.156                    64     latest/stable    slack✓                 -

Comment: I had an extremely similar problem with chrome

Comment: I was not able to fix it, but the workaround is to start electron-based apps like this:
`slack --disable-dev-shm-usage` with additional flag